# Add custom lines in ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, lines

I created this plot
[image]

with this code:

```
ggplot(data_long, aes(Trial,value,fill=factor(Trial))) +    
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar") + facet_grid(Task~Gruppo) + labs(x="Trial 
    type",y="Accuracy %") + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Now, I need to add custom lines that show the differences between couples of values. Here is an example of what I want to do (see the first two bars with p = 0.46):

[image]

I have no idea about solution, and the things are also more complicated for me since I used `facet_grid`.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, as sample data are not provided, made my own sample data. Those data are already summarized (there is only one value per each combinations of levels.

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(expand.grid(c("Control","Effect"),c("Self","Other"),c("Type1","Type2")),
     runif(8,0,1))
colnames(df)<-c("Treatment","Group","Type","value")
df
  Treatment Group  Type     value
1   Control  Self Type1 0.2655087
2    Effect  Self Type1 0.3721239
3   Control Other Type1 0.5728534
4    Effect Other Type1 0.9082078
5   Control  Self Type2 0.2016819
6    Effect  Self Type2 0.8983897
7   Control Other Type2 0.9446753
8    Effect Other Type2 0.6607978
```

Now you need to add two new values for the positions of lines. `ymin` value is the original value plus small constant. `ymax` value is calculated for each facet (using `Treatment` and `Type` as grouping) and it is maximal value in facet plus some constant.

```
library(plyr)
df<-ddply(df,.(Treatment,Type),transform,ymax=max(value)+0.2)
df$ymin<-df$value+0.05
df
  Treatment Group  Type     value      ymax      ymin
1   Control  Self Type1 0.2655087 0.7728534 0.3155087
2   Control  Self Type2 0.2016819 1.1446753 0.2516819
3   Control Other Type1 0.5728534 0.7728534 0.6228534
4   Control Other Type2 0.9446753 1.1446753 0.9946753
5    Effect  Self Type1 0.3721239 1.1082078 0.4221239
6    Effect  Self Type2 0.8983897 1.0983897 0.9483897
7    Effect Other Type1 0.9082078 1.1082078 0.9582078
8    Effect Other Type2 0.6607978 1.0983897 0.7107978
```

Second data frame is made for the labels. Here in each facet y position is again original `ymax` value plus some constant and `lab` contains labels you need to display.

```
df.names<-ddply(df,.(Treatment,Type),summarise,ymax=ymax[1]+0.1)
df.names$lab<-c("p=0.46","**","***","*")
df.names
  Treatment  Type      ymax    lab
1   Control Type1 0.8728534 p=0.46
2   Control Type2 1.2446753     **
3    Effect Type1 1.2082078    ***
4    Effect Type2 1.1983897      *
```

As now `df` is already summarized value use `geom_bar(stat="identity")` instead of `stat_summary()`. Additional lines are added with two `geom_segment()` calls - first one plots vertical lines and second adds horizontal line. `geom_text()` adds labels above the lines.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Group,value,fill=Group)) +    
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(Type~Treatment) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=Group,xend=Group,y=ymin,yend=ymax))+
  geom_segment(aes(x="Self",xend="Other",y=ymax,yend=ymax))+
  geom_text(data=df.names,aes(x=1.5,y=ymax,label=lab),inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Very thanks for your patience, Didzis. It is very clear and complete for me.